# Provide a link to allow users to email our company even if they do not have outlook/outlook express installed

Tags: html, email

We want to put a link on our site "Subscribe",  when you click this link this is the href

```
href="mailto:subscriber@org.com&subject=i want to subscribe?body=whatever"
```

This works great, it's super easy too, but the problem is for anyone who does not have outlook/outlook express installed.

Without real development of any new features is it possible to make this work for gmail/yahoo/aol/etc.... email users?

Comment: You've got the `&` and the `?` in the wrong place in that link. They should be swapped.

Comment: Sorry it was just an example of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mailto` URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) works in all browsers and only in email clients that support it.

In essence, when clicked it will launch the default email client on the computer and set the to address, subject and body.

You can't make it work in a web based email client, since they can't be set as default email clients.

Comment: your absolutely right.  Maybe I need to tweak my question, I want to know if there is a way in addition to mailto that will work for these non outlook people.  I know mailto will only open their currently installed and configured mail client. not webbased.

Comment: @Doug - Can you explain exactly why you want to happen? As far as I know, there is nothing you can do that will start a new email in a web based email client, unless you can program directly against the API.

Comment: You have answered the main part of my question.  I wanted to make sure I had no options before heading down the development/CGI path.

Answer (score 0):

The action that takes place when a user clicks on a "mailto" link is end user dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way with HTML to determine whether or not a client has Outlook or other client apps installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can sidestep all email clients/webmail services if you instead have a form for submitting messages, with a place to put the email address the company should reply to. A simple CGI or PHP script can turn that to an email on the server side.

This page has a PHP example. http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mail.asp

Comment: Fail on php....I have no way, minus an act of congress to get php to run.  I'll update my questions tags.